# Why is my nested for loop not displaying Hello World 2

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

Here is my nested for loop.

```
int c = 1;
for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
    if (c == 6) {
        System.out.println("Hello World 1");
    } else if (c == 7) {
        System.out.println("Hello World 2");
    }
    for (int e = 0; e < 5; e++) {
        System.out.println("This is the nested for loop :" +c);
        c++;
    }
}
```

This is what my console is printing out.

```
This is the nested for loop :1
This is the nested for loop :2
This is the nested for loop :3
This is the nested for loop :4
This is the nested for loop :5
Hello World 1
This is the nested for loop :6
This is the nested for loop :7
This is the nested for loop :8
```

And it continues printing this until it reach's 50 and does not display Hello World 2.

Comment: Because `c` is never 7 when the `else if` executes.

Comment: Well, did you step through each line of code in the debugger, and example the variable values?  That is the first thing to do.

Comment: @OldProgrammer The existing `println()` statements are sufficient for debugging purposes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add comments to your current code. Read this code by going through the steps 1 to 7 in order.

```
int c = 1;
for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
    // 1. When we are here for the first time, c = 1, both if are false
    // 4. Now, c is equal to 6 so the first if is true, "Hello World 1" is printed
    // 7. Now, c is equal to 11, both if are false, nothing is printed...
    if (c == 6) {
        System.out.println("Hello World 1");
    } else if (c == 7) {
        System.out.println("Hello World 2");
    }
    for (int e = 0; e < 5; e++) {
        // 2. We reach here, c is incremented 5 times.
        // 5. c is incremented again 5 times
        System.out.println("This is the nested for loop :" +c);
        c++;
    }
    // 3. When we're here, c that was 1 is now 6 (incremented 5 times in step 2)
    // 6. When we're here for the second time, c is now 11 (6 incremented 5 times in step 5)
}
```

Basically, at the start of the first `for`, `c` is 1, then 6, then 11... but never 7, so `"Hello World 2"` is never printed.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, completely understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

When the nested loop involving integer "e" runs through the first time, c is incrimented from 1 to 6. 'c' is 6 upon exiting this loop, so "Hello world 1" is printed to the console. Then, the loop involving 'e' is called upon once more, incrimenting 'c' five more times up to 11 before the loop is exited, meaning that 'c' = 11 the next time the first loop runs through, since it is incrimented five times per run of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your output already answers your question. Remember that Java executes code exactly in the order which you type it. Let's think about the order of execution of your code:

1. `c` starts at 1.
2. `d` starts at 0 and the `if` statement is skipped because none of the conditions are true.
3. The nested for loop increments `c` 6.
4. `d` increments to 1 and the `if` statement prints out `Hello World 1`.
5. The nested for loop increments `c` to 11.
6. `d` increments to 2 and the `if` statement is skipped because `c` is neither 6 nor 7.
7. Execution continues until `d` reaches 10.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following loop:

```
for (int e = 0; e < 5; e++) {
        System.out.println("This is the nested for loop :" +c);
        c++;
}
```

You increment c 5 times for each of the 10 iterations of the outer loop.
This means that when the *if* statement checks if *c = 7*, it will be either 1, 6, 11, 16, etc. As the condition is never met, the message is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

you may remove the else condition before -

```
 else if (c ==7){
    }
```

and write, only -

```
if (c==7){}
```

Because in you code when `c` reaches 6 then it skip the test `c==7`